# Why is oxygen more stable than oxygen dication?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, stability

According to molecular orbital theory (MOT), $\ce{O2^2+}$ has a greater bond order than $\ce{O2}$ and two less antibonding electrons. So why is molecular oxygen $\ce{O2}$ more stable than the molecular ion $\ce{O2^2+}?$

One possible reason that comes to mind is that the antibonding (AB) orbitals, although higher in energy than the constituent atomic orbitals, are still negative in energy, so adding electrons to AB orbitals still lowers the energy. But then, by that same argument, $\ce{O2-}$ would increase stability further, which it doesn't. Am I overlooking anything?

**Note:** I know that from an electrostatics point of view, $\ce{O2}$ is obviously more stable as bring two negative electrons close to positive $\ce{O2^2+}$ decreases the electric potential energy of the system. I am interested in how MOT explains relative stability (or if it actually even does).

Comment: You have to distinguish reactivity (with commonly found substances such as water and other components in air) and bond strength. Just because something has a strong bond doesn't mean it does not react - just compare alkanes and alkenes and alkynes.

Comment: I am strictly talking about thermodynamic stability. O2 is more thermodynamically stable than O2+2 by elementary electrostatics, but MOT predicts otherwise. I am asking for an explanation for this

Comment: You can only compare substances when they have the same set of atoms and the same charge. How would you assign thermodynamic values to a naked electron?

Comment: Well, I think it is *not* more stable. For cation enthalpy is lower, bond stronger, *but*... getting those electrons still gives off energy, by aforementioned electrostatics. So, why try to get answer when you already have it?

Comment: @Mithoron I'm afraid I don't understand. O2 is NΟΤ more (energetically) stable?

Comment: How can it not be more energetically stable if adding electrons to the dication releases energy?

Comment: If you compare just the two things - the cation is just better, but if you add electrons to the picture, ah then pesky charge sucks them up and spits out surplus energy. It's like Earth is perfectly OK without the Moon, but if the satellite didn't have enough energy to stay in orbit, it would crash, big boom lots of energy comes off, but result has still more internal energy then Earth in the beginning, being bigger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to consider the system as a whole - you can't directly compare $\ce{O_2}$ and $\ce{O_2^2+}$ because they have different numbers of particles. To put it another way when you consider the relative stability of two interconvertible specifies you really have to write down a chemical reaction that connects them, and then consider which direction is thermodynamically favoured, and *then* consider whether it is kinetically feasible. Stability is a really tricky and more often than not misused word!

So here we have to look at $$
\ce{O_2 -> O_2^2+ +2e^-}
$$

As you note $\ce{O_2^2+}$ has a stronger bond than $\ce{O_2}$. But that is not all that is going on. We are also binding two electrons to the Oxygens - how does that affect the energetics? Well the reaction above is simply the sum of the following processes

$$
\ce{O_2 -> O_2^+ +e^-}
$$
$$
\ce{O_2^+ -> O_2^2+ +e^-}
$$

In other words the energy required is the sum of the first two ionisation energies of molecular oxygen. Do we know these? Well after a good 10 seconds looking I can't find the second energy, but the first is very well known, it is after all related to the discovery of compounds of Xenon and the start of noble gas chemistry. It is 12.0697 eV (from https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7782447&Mask=20) which in more familiar units is 1165 kJ/mol - a huge energy, bigger than any bond energy I am aware of, and note there is *at least* this much to come as the second ionisation energy will be even larger, as it is pulling a negative electron away from an already positively charge centre. Thus the energy gained by attaching the two electrons will massively out weigh any increase in bonding in the molecule.

Can we relate this to MO theory? Well as Koopman's theorem tells us the ionisation energy is an approximation of the orbital energy, this is telling us that relative to having a free electron it is more energetically favourable to put the electron in the lowest energy unoccupied orbital in the molecule. That this orbital is antibonding is irrelevant. Antibonding simply means it weakens any bonding in the molecule; it doesn't say anything about the energy of that orbital relative to the free electron. And you know this must be true - many molecules have electrons in antibonding orbitals and those electrons don't just rush away to infinity, hence occupying the orbital must be a lower energy proposition for the electron compared to being unbound. Thus $\ce{O_2}$ is thermodynamically more stable than $\ce{O_2^2+}$ and two free electrons because the decrease in energy caused by the electrons occupying the highest unoccupied molecular orbitals is (much) greater than any possible decrease in the bond energy.

That's the thermodynamics. Kinetics is difficult in general, but very unlikely to be an issue here. At this point I chicken out.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that the bond order in MOT and the 'stability" it describes is relative to the unbonded state, NOT infinite separation of each electric particle, and O2 & O2+2 have unbonded state with different energies (infinitely separated atoms vs infinitely separated cations)? If this is correct, wouldn't that nullify the use of MOT comparing relative stability (which is pretty much all we use it for at this level)

Comment: Secondly, what do you exactly mean by the extent of "bonding"/bond energy ? Wouldn't having more electrons in the system further lowering the electric p.e make it more difficult to pull the nuclei apart and thus increase bond energy too?

Comment: Not totally sure I understand what you are saying, but I'm taking it as saying that you have to be careful in making sure you have a consistent zero of energy. If so yes, obviously. If you do that you can make meaningful energetic comparisons. That this is poorly taught or even omitted is a different matter - and that observation may very well be true but I have been out of the education system at least for below graduate level for so long that I don't nowadays feel qualifies to comment.

Comment: To your second comment - they go into antibonding orbitals. What do antibonding orbitals do?

Comment: Oh ok. I was picturing the 2 extra electrons between the nuclei for some reason.  A quick refresher on antibonding electron densities explains this. So basically, while it is more difficult to pull apart each electron from the nucleus in the molecule, it is more difficult to (symmetrically?) pull apart the 2 nuclei in the dication?

Comment: All in all, would it be more accurate to describe the bond order s a measure of bon energy as opposed to thermodynamic stability?(extremely sorry for continuously bothering you )

Comment: Careful about thermodynamic stability - you have to consider that in the context of the WHOLE system. But "would it be more accurate to describe the bond order as a measure of bond energy", yes, precisely. Bond order applies to the isolated molecule, and is independent of the environment molecule is in (more or less). Thermodynamic stability requires the whole system to be considered.